# How can I turn off the lights on my Logitech G413 SE keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, devuan, keyboard-backlight

I got a Logitech G413 SE keyboard. Its keys are lit when I plug it in; I want to turn that light off; but - there is no "lights off" switch on it! Damn them.

Logitech has all sorts of software to do this on Windows. But - how can I turn off the lights on a Linux system?

I'd prefer something that can work even from the command-line, but even a closed-source GUI utility is better than nothing...

My distribution: Devuan GNU/Linux Daedalus.

Comment: openrgb *may* be able to help

Answer (score 1):

You can control your keyboard’s LEDs using [g810-led](https://github.com/MatMoul/g810-led). It’s available as the `g810-led` package in Debian, I don’t know about Devuan.

On my G610,

```
g610-led -a 0
```

switches the LEDs off; presumably something similar will work using `g413-led` on your keyboard.

You may need to run this as root.

Comment: `g810-led` needs `udev` to work out-of-the-box, which is why I wasn’t sure how well it would work in Devuan. If you run it as root it should work in any case.

Comment: I am running as root, but - what do I do with it?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: 1. You're supposed to provide an answer, not quiz me about a utility you mentioned... 2. `g810-led --print-device` gives `Matching or compatible device not found`. `g810-led -dv 046d -dp c349 -tuk 1 -a 000000` gives `Error: Can not write to hidraw, try with the libusb version` but I think that might just be bad syntax.

Comment: Since I don’t have your keyboard, I can’t give you a complete answer without your help. I showed you what works for me, and told you what command to use; but presumably that doesn’t work for you. I have an idea of what might be causing the `hidraw` errors, but I can’t check right now.

Comment: Ok, now I see the edit to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any `hidraw` devices (`/dev/hidraw0` etc.)?

Comment: Yes, `/dev/hidraw0` ... `/dev/hidraw3`.

Comment: g413-led is for 431 carbon and do not work (2023-12) for 431 SE
I searched how to make dump, but the project do not provide enough information.